# How to match one expression and not match another

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I am trying to create a .NET regular expression (for use in a ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator control) that matches a name in the format [First Name][Space][Surname] but does *not* match if a specific name is entered, say Mickey Mouse

This expression works for the first part:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s{1}[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```

And this *seems* to work for the second part:

```
[^Mickey Mouse]
```

but I can't seem to be combine these two together into one expression

Comment: `!myString.Contains("Mickey Mouse")`. Don't try to do too much in one Regex.

Comment: `[^Mickey Mouse]` just means "non of the characters in `Mickey Mouse`. It could very well fail for valid entries.

Comment: @oded - Thanks but I want to do this client side in my ASP.NET page (see edit to the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are currently using is a negated character class. It matches a single character that doesn't belong to the set of characters `M`, `i`, `c`, `k` ... You get the idea.

If you want to ensure your string isn't the sequence `Mickey Mouse`, you need to use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!Mickey Mouse$)[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```